# Deleting a row from an iOS table view

Tags: ios, tables, mobile-application, iphone

In iOS applications what is the recommended way to delete a row from a [table view](https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/3429/First.png). The table view is displaying a list of topics.

Should I be swiping on the row to remove it or pressing edit at the top then selecting the row to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gestures are fairly undiscoverable—not obvious at first glance.

With gestures on iPhone:

- Provide another way to do the same action. For example, in the Mail app, users can swipe to delete or can use the **Edit** button to reach the **Delete** command.
- Assign the gesture to functions that aren't critical. For example, it's possible users will try to navigate with a swipe, and you wouldn't want to design for accidental deletion.

It's OK if the non-gesture alternative to **Delete** takes several taps along an indirect route *unless deleting is a critical function* in your app. if ti's critical, swipe can reveal an additional step to Delete:

[image: Swipe can reveal additional commands]

That gives you several options. I hope these help you to move forward.